# OpenMP: How to implement loop scheduling without for loops?

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, scheduled-tasks, openmp

I got this homework:

> Implement an OpenMP program that generates prime numbers in a given
>   interval. You should use the prime generation method given in the next
>   page ( Do NOT use other method !). Your program should generate a csv
>   le called results.csv that reports the timing results in the
>   following format.

[Table needed to be output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJMv0.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 50
main()
{
int prime[N] ;
int j ;
int k ;
int n ;
int quo,rem ;
P1: prime[0] = 2 ;
n = 3 ;
j = 0 ;
P2: j = j+1 ;
prime[j] = n ;
P3: if (j == (N-1)) goto P9 ;
P4: n = n + 2 ;
P5: k = 1 ;
P6: quo = n / prime[k] ;
rem = n % prime[k] ;
if (rem == 0) goto P4 ;
P7: if (quo <= prime[k]) goto P2 ;
P8: k = k+1 ;
goto P6 ;
P9: for(j=0 ; j < N ; j++) printf("%d ",prime[j]) ;
}
```

I don't know any method to configure static, dynamic, guided scheduling without for loops and since I can not change the method, how do I do that?

Comment: How about a ``while`` loop???

Comment: Between P2 and P9?

Comment: As far as I can tell the programm as presenteed here is working. What is your expected output and what do you get instead. That might help us understanding your problem. Because in all honesty I have no clue what your problem is...

Comment: The problem is, I know that for loops can be scheduled like :#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) private(tmp, i, j, k) etc. But in this situation, where could I put the for loops to schedule? You can see the expected output above the link in the question: 'Table needed to be output'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Working with labels in OpenMP: How to or is it possible to jump in Threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36103310/working-with-labels-in-openmp-how-to-or-is-it-possible-to-jump-in-threads)